# How I can center a block vertically and horizontally with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this form:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="span5 well">
<h2>Authentification</h2>
<form method="POST">...</form>
</div>
</div>
```

How I can center that block (div span5 well) vertically and horizontally? Thank you.

Comment: Within the container or within the body?

Comment: Is it correct? At container, if it accessible...

Answer (score 15):

Horizontal centering can be done by adding `margin: 0 auto` to an element that has no siblings.

Answer (score 3):

```
<style>
.well
{       
    position:absolute;      
    width:200px;    
    height:200px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top:-100px; /* negative number 1/2 height */
    margin-left:-100px; /* negative number 1/2 width */
    outline:1px solid #CCC;
}
</style>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="span5 well">
<h2>Authentification</h2>
<form method="POST">...</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this only works if you know the height of the element (200px in this case)

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing conflicting with Bootstrap to use some JS for this, such as [this guy's JQuery.vAlign plugin](http://www.nitinh.com/2010/01/vertical-align-middle-using-javascript-jquery-mootools/).  I find that more straight-forward than the vertical-align tricks.

Answer (score 0):

Horizontal centering was mentioned earlier to set margin 0 auto.

To vertically align the element dynamically (when you don't know the height) you can relatively shift it 50% (up or down) and then use transform: translateY(50%) (+/-) to center it within its parent container:

```
div.span5 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    top:50%;
    width:400px;
    position:relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uq52u5k6/)